# Not able to read PGP private key using openpgp library - Misformed armored text

Tags: node.js, encryption, aws-lambda, pgp, openpgp

I am getting private key from an object in secret mangers(aws) where it stores public key, private key and pass phrase in the same object. When I try to decode and read private key(base64) using

```
const decoded_key = Buffer.from(<private key>, 'base64').toString('ascii');
const private_key = openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: decoded_key });
```

I get the error that Misformed armored text
I am able to decode and import this key in terminal(mac) but its not working in the lambda function using commands above. Please help!

My object from secret manager looks like this

```
const secretValue = {
"publicKeyBase64": <public key>,
"privateKeyBase64": <private key>,
"passphrase": <passphrase>
}
```